# adding string as integer

Tags: android, string

in my application i have got 0.00 in edit text.next when i enter 2or3 or any digit its getting concat with 0.00 and getting 0.003.

```
if(item.equals("0.00")){
            item=item+string;}
```

i changed the code.but this time too its getting an error

```
if(item.equals("0.00")){
            int a=Integer.parseInt(item.toString());
            int b=Integer.parseInt(string.toString());
            int c=a+b;
            item=String.valueOf(c);}
```

Comment: Could You provide more details? What are You trying to achieve? What is exact question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using decimal places then you will want to use a data type that supports those, such as `double`. Try this:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(item.toString());
```

NOTE: If both your variables are of string type, then you won't need to use `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

You want O.OO but still using Integer. Try using FLOAT.

Also, FLOAT is NEVER a perfect value. So you might have .XX added.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error, because `"0.00"` has decimal places, so it is parsed as a floating point number, not integer.

Parse it as a `double`:

```
String item = "0.00";
double result = Double.parseDouble(item) + 0.03; // result is 0.03
```